# Cocoapods : no such module

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I am using Xcode 7.3 and have just updated my code to swift 2.3 (not sure if it is realted).
My project includes many pods, like Google, Alamofire, FBSDK ...

When I try to build my project, it fails with this error on "Import Google":
"No such module Google"

Obviously, if I comment this line, it fails on next import :
"No such module FBSDKLoginKit"

Here is my podfile :

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'MyProject' do
pod 'Cartography'
pod 'Google/SignIn'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.5'
pod 'UIImageView-Letters'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'iCarousel'
pod 'ActionSheetPicker-3.0'
pod 'Stripe'
pod 'DateTools'
pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK'
pod 'DLRadioButton'
pod 'p2.OAuth2' 
end

target 'MyProjectTests' do

end

target 'MyProjectUITests' do

end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3'
        end
    end
end
```

what can I do to solve this problem ?
(I already tried pod install, pod update, Clean, Clear Derived Data...)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

In your app's *project*-Bridging-Header.h file, import the Google Sign-In SDK headers like this:

```
#import <Google/SignIn.h>
```

[as described here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift).

No need to do "`#import <Google>`" anywhere else.